# Add project folder in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I want to copy my project files/folders that contains all my python-related files and subfolders to add to the docker var container

Docker container-->Files-->var

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to copy my project folder that contains all my python-related files and subfolders to add to the docker var container.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Are you sure you want to **copy** your files into the container? Or would it be sufficient to solely mount a local folder into the container? Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide much information, so I try to guess what you need.

I think you should use [Docker volume mounting](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) by:

`docker run -v /local/project/folder:/var/project/folder # ... other options ...`